# Facebook account kit localization issue in ios

Tags: facebook

My app is localized with three  languages also i am using  account kit in my app for login, i have'nt write any code for localization of account kit but its taking the previously selected language. Is there any way to change the account kit language from code.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/accountkit/ios/customizing#localization - should work automatically, according to that. (If it doesn’t for you, then you are maybe not handling localization correctly in your app to begin with.)

Comment: Yes I have followed the same steps from the above link, but in that link, there is noting for the language localization, its all about the UI and color themes, is there any option to set any default language to the account kit.